# How do I merge these two objects into a single set?

Tags: terraform

I want to merge var.network_rules with local.default_network_rules so that it can be created using the azurerm_storage_account_network_rules resource:

`locals.tf`:

```
      default_network_rules = [
    {
      default_action = "Deny"
      ip_rules = [
        "IP_string"
      ]
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = []
    }
  ]
```

`variables.tf`:

```
variable "network_rules" {
  description = "(Optional) Additional network rules for the storage account."
  type = list(object({
    default_action = string
    ip_rules = list(string)
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = list(string)
  }))
  default = [ 
    {
      default_action = null
      ip_rules = null
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = null
    } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Merge exactly how? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: I want to be able to create a set of network rules with azurerm_storage_account_network_rules that include both the variable and the local rules.

Comment: The question lacks a lot of information about what is the current type of the two variables, and what is the desired type layout you are looking for. Anyway, you may be watching for a function like `merge` (docs https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Use a `map` instead of a `list` for both variables and then use the [merge](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) function.

Please note that when you merge maps in Terraform, if a key exists in both maps, the value from the second map will overwrite the value from the first map.

Example:

```hcl
################################################################## variables.tf

variable "network_rules" {
  description = "(Optional) Additional network rules for the storage account."
  type = map(object({
    default_action             = string
    ip_rules                   = list(string)
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "rule1" = {
      default_action = "Allow"
      ip_rules = [
        "192.168.1.1",
        "192.168.1.2"
      ]
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
        "other_subnet_id_01",
        "other_subnet_id_02"
      ]
    },
    "rule2" = {
      default_action = "Deny"
      ip_rules       = ["192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.2"]
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
        "other_subnet_id_03",
        "other_subnet_id_04"
      ]
    }
  }
}

####################################################################### main.tf

locals {

  default_network_rules = {
    "default_rule1" = {
      default_action = "Deny"
      ip_rules = [
        "192.168.3.1",
        "192.168.3.2"
      ]
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
        "default_subnet_id_01",
        "default_subnet_id_03"
      ]
    },
    "default_rule2" = {
      default_action = "Allow"
      ip_rules = [
        "192.168.4.1",
        "192.168.4.2"
      ]
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
        "default_subnet_id_03",
        "default_subnet_id_04"
      ]
    }
  }

  all_rules = merge(local.default_network_rules, var.network_rules)
}

# dummy resource for testing purposes
resource "null_resource" "network_rules" {
  for_each = local.all_rules
  triggers = {
    default_action             = each.value.default_action
    ip_rules                   = join(",", each.value.ip_rules)
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = join(",", each.value.virtual_network_subnet_ids)
  }
}
```

Output of `terraform plan`:

```txt
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.network_rules["default_rule1"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "network_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "default_action"             = "Deny"
          + "ip_rules"                   = "192.168.3.1,192.168.3.2"
          + "virtual_network_subnet_ids" = "default_subnet_id_01,default_subnet_id_03"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.network_rules["default_rule2"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "network_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "default_action"             = "Allow"
          + "ip_rules"                   = "192.168.4.1,192.168.4.2"
          + "virtual_network_subnet_ids" = "default_subnet_id_03,default_subnet_id_04"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.network_rules["rule1"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "network_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "default_action"             = "Allow"
          + "ip_rules"                   = "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2"
          + "virtual_network_subnet_ids" = "other_subnet_id_01,other_subnet_id_02"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.network_rules["rule2"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "network_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "default_action"             = "Deny"
          + "ip_rules"                   = "192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2"
          + "virtual_network_subnet_ids" = "other_subnet_id_03,other_subnet_id_04"
        }
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Also, when creating resources using a `for_each` loop in Terraform, it's generally better to use a `map` rather than a `list`.

The reason is that `for_each` with a `map` allows you to create and manage resources in a way that's *resilient to reordering*. If you use a `list`, and the order of the `list` changes, Terraform will see this as a need to destroy and recreate resources, which is often not what you want.

When you use a `map` each resource is associated with a key (e.g. `null_resource.network_rules["default_rule1"]`). Terraform uses these keys to identify resources. This means that if the order of the items in the `map` changes, Terraform will still know which resource corresponds to which item.